# $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $x$, Lipschitz in $y$. Is it bounded?

Tags: calculus

Let $R =\{(x,y)| \text{  }|x-x_0|\leq a, |y-y_0|\leq b\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ be some bounded, closed, rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$.

$f(x,y):R \to\mathbb R$ is continuous in $x$, and Lipschitz in $y$. Is there a constant $M \geq 0$ such that $\forall (x,y) \in D: \text{   } |f(x,y)| < M$?

I've shown that $|f(x,y_1)-(x,y_2)| \leq 2bL$ for any $(x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in D$, so that's a start. Don't know where to go from here. I'm not even sure that the statement is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes** if $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz in $y$ (i.e. the Lipschitz constant $L$ does not depend on $x$).

Since $f$ is continuous in $x$, there is $K$ such that $|f(x,y_0)| \le K$ for all $x$. Then 
$$
|f(x,y)| \le |f(x,y) - f(x,y_0)| + |f(x,y_0)| \le K + Lb \, . 
$$

Comment: Triangle inequality strikes again...Should practice that at least 17 more times every day.